# Jquery prop.("disabled",true) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a simple disabling and enabling of checkbox based on the status of another checkbox. I am having trouble disabling the checkbox by using `prop("disabled", true)`. But It is not working. I tried using the `prop("checked", true)` and it works well. I don't why `prop("disabled", true)` is not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group question-option-block form-group">
    <label for="option[]" class="control-label">Options</label>    
    <div class="row" style="">
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-8"><input class="form-control question-option" name="option[]" type="text" value="0" id="option[]"></div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" class="open_ended_answers" name="open_ended_answers[]" value="1"> Open-ended </div>
       <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-1"> <input type="checkbox" class="required_open_answers" name="required_open_answers[]" value="1"> Required</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-8"><input class="form-control question-option" name="option[]" type="text" value="1" id="option[]"></div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" class="open_ended_answers" name="open_ended_answers[]" value="1"> Open-ended </div>
       <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-1"> <input type="checkbox" class="required_open_answers" name="required_open_answers[]" value="1"> Required</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-8"><input class="form-control question-option" name="option[]" type="text" value="2" id="option[]"></div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" class="open_ended_answers" name="open_ended_answers[]" value="1"> Open-ended </div>
       <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-1"> <input type="checkbox" class="required_open_answers" name="required_open_answers[]" value="1"> Required</div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-flat remove-option">Remove</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.open_ended_answers').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest('.row').find(".required_open_answers").prop('disabled',false);
    }
    else{
      $(this).closest('.row').find(".required_open_answers").prop('disabled',true);
      $(this).closest('.row').find(".required_open_answers").prop('checked',false);
    }
});

if(required_open_answers != null){
    required_open_answers_input.each(function(i,val) {
        if(required_open_answers[i] !== undefined) {
            if(open_ended[i] == "1"){
              $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            }else{
              $(this).prop("disabled", false);
            }
            if(required_open_answers[i] == "1"){
              $(this).prop("checked",true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: drop your parsed html here

Comment: Is it the code within the `.change()` handler that you're asking about? What is the second block of code?

Comment: I am sure $(this).prop("disabled", true); works just fine. Are you sure the the flow runs to that statement?

Comment: @nnnnnn the first code is for the on change handler. while the second line of code is included in the on ready handler for first run. Checking existing values.

Comment: @vothaison Yes I am, I tried changing the code to change a text and it run wells. And I believe $(this).prop("disabled", true) is working fine cause I used it to other input elements and it is working just fine. But for some reason it is not working on this specific area. I am not sure why.

Comment: Please provide more context with HTML. At the moment we are guessing what your HTML structure is. If you can, please include edit your question and add the HTML in a snippet, the <> button in the editor. That will provide an interactive example of the problem you have. Also check for any console errors and report those.

Comment: @JonP I included the html code in the question

Answer (score 23):

**For jQuery 1.6+**

User can use .prop() function:

```
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
$("input").prop("disabled", false);
```

**For jQuery 1.5 and below**

You need to use `.attr()` and disable the checkbox

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

and for re enable the checkbox (remove attribute entirely):

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Assuming you have an event handler on a checkbox, in any version of jQuery you can use the following property to check if your checkbox is enabled or not

```
if (this.disabled){
   // your logic here
}
```

More information at:

http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc-1

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Used both removeAttr and attr with no luck.

Comment: @banri16 please edit your question, adding a jsfiddle (html included) where you reproduce the error, I would be glad help you to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I included the html code in my question. I tried to reproduce the error in jsfiddle but It is hard to reproduce since I am using laravel framework. Tried to code it but it was working fine. I think it is a problem in the code flow.

Comment: I'm already using prop isn't OP using .prop...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting the desired output using `prop("disabled", true)`, try

```
$(this).attr("disabled", true)
```

Comment: I also tried this one but unfortunately it is not also working

Comment: you got the solution?

Comment: yes, it was in a change handler. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay that's great.

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript instead

```
$.each(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), (element) => {
  element.disabled = true;
});
```

Or, in your case

```
this.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks but I found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Replace this :

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
              $(this).closest('.row').find(".required_open_answers").prop('disabled',false);
            }
```

with

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('div[class*="row"]').find(".required_open_answers").prop('disabled',false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. There was a change handler for a document which enable all inputs which overrides my script. I changed this code

```
$(document).on("change", questionType, function() {
        if(questionType.val() == 0) {
            changeOption(0);
        }else if(questionType.val() == 2){
            changeOption(2);
        }else {
            changeOption(1);
        }
    });
```

to

```
$(questionType).on("change", function() {
        if(questionType.val() == 0) {
            changeOption(0);
        }else if(questionType.val() == 2){
            changeOption(2);
        }else{
          changeOption(1);
        }
    });
```

ChangeOption() include process of enabling all the input elements. Thank you so much for all of your help.